# How to draw simply-laced Dynkin diagram in TikZ-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know how I could draw the following:

[image]

Comment: Try the dynkin-diagrams package on CTAN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=-]
D_r{:} &[-2em] \bullet \arrow[r] & \bullet \cdots \bullet \arrow[r] &
  \bullet \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & \bullet \\
& & & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The dynkin-diagrams package doesn't offer D series diagrams with this layout, but you might prefer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\(D_r\) \dynkin{D}{}
\end{document}
```